# The greatest negative integer satisfying $x^2-4x-77<0$ and $x^2>4$ is

Tags: inequality

For $$x^2-4x-77<0$$
$$x^2+7x-11x-77<0$$
$$x(x+7)-11(x+7)<0$$
$$(x-11)(x+7)<0$$
Therefore 
$x\in (-7,11)$

And $$x^2>4$$
$x\in(-\infty, -2)\cup(2,\infty)$
So the greatest negative integer satisfying the equation should be -6, but answer given is -10. How do we arrive at that?

Comment: The given answer is false.

Comment: Well, you can easily see that $$(-10)^2 - 4(-10) - 77 = 63 >0$$

Comment: But $x=-6$ works!

Comment: Please use "negative number of greatest magnitude" instead of "greatest negative number" to [avoid ambiguity](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/13680/9510).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arrive at that answer by (incorrectly) flipping a sign in the first inequality so it reads
$$x^2\boxed{+}4x-77<0\text{.}$$
Then the solution to that inequality is $x\in(-11,7)$; *mutatis mutandis* you get $x=-10$.

Answer (score 0):

x² - 4x - 77 < 0
x² - 11x + 7x - 77 < 0
x(x - 11) + 7(x - 11)  < 0
(x +7 )(x - 11)  < 0

So,
  x ⋲ (-7 ,11)

Again,

x² > 4
x² - 4 > 0
(x + 2)(x - 2) > 0

x ⋲ (-∞ , -2) U (2, ∞)

x ⋲ (-7,11) is the common solution for both conditions taken together.

Now , GREATEST ""NEGATIVE"" INTEGER = -3

Do not  forget , smaller the number in negative , greater is its value compared to other negative numbers.

Here , from the Range x ⋲ (-7,11) , the negative numbers  are -6, -5 , -4 , -3 ,-2 ,-1 . (-7 not included)

And for satisfying x ⋲(-∞ , -2) U (2,∞) ,
The negative numbers we have now are -6,-5,-4,-3 (-2 not included)

The greatest negative number among -6,-5,-4,-3 is (-3)